# Little Notation question

Tags: functions, notation

for example I have the equation $2y=4x$ and I want to solve it for $x$, (sure, $x = \frac{1}{2} y$, but how can I just write, that I want to solve it for $x$?

Regards

Comment: How do you want to write this? So that it is immediately clear from seeing the equation that you want to solve it for $x$?
I suppose just writing:
'I want to solve the following for $x$: $2y=4x$' is not what you are thinking of...

Comment: I think Jan's mentioned in his comment (the only?) one possibility: you have to specifically write "solve for $\,x\,$...etc." since I don't think there's some symbol or special code for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use as many words as you like when writing mathematics.  It just makes things cumbersome if you use words instead of symbols when dealing with complicated problems, but that doesn't change the content of what you're writing.  So, here you can write "I want to solve two times y equals four times x for x."  Or you could write "I want to solve 2y=4x for x."